# Rails 3 WYSIWYG that supports image uploads?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, wysiwyg

Are there any gems/plugins for rails which would take all the hassle out of having a WYSIWYG editor which supports image uploads (ideally something that works with paperclip) ?

Comment: might want to accept some answers to ensure you get answers to this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885006/rails-3-and-rich-text-editor/5885956#5885956 .

Answer (score 1):

This one has been recommended before: https://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce